# How to remove ordinal indicators of the Portuguese language string

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

In portuguese several names have the following characters:

```
feminine ª
and 
masculine º
```

I need to remove them from my string, but I can't find the right regex. Anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it works, very strange, but works.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(string = inep$NO_ENTIDADE, pattern = "�", replacement = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Portuguese ASCII code page is [CP860](https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp860.html). And the codes for those characters are

- Feminine ª  - `\xa6`
- Masculine º - `\xa7`

So you can `iconv` them to your locale and then `sub` or `gsub`.

```
fem <- iconv('\xa6', 'CP860', 'UTF-8')
masc <- iconv('\xa7', 'CP860', 'UTF-8')

s <- c('feminine ª', 'masculine º')

sub(fem, '', s)
#[1] "feminine "   "masculine º"

sub(masc, '', s)
#[1] "feminine ª" "masculine "
```